# Read everything from child_process.spawn's stderr in nodejs

Tags: node.js, buffer, child-process

Trying to run `fping` from nodejs via `child_process.spawn()` is and capturing output via `cp.stderr.on('data')` sometimes results in incomplete data in the buffer. Here's my sample snippet:

```
const ChildProcess = require('child_process');

const args = [
                '-A','-c10','-b1472','-B1',
                '-r0','-O0','-q', '-p100',
                'google.com', 'slack.com', 'github.com'
            ];

function runChildProcess() {
    const child = ChildProcess.spawn('fping', args);

    child.on('exit', (code) => 
        console.log('Process exited with code', code)
    );

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('stdout:', data.toString().length, 'chars');
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('stderr:', data.toString().length, 'chars');
    });

}

setInterval(runChildProcess, 1500);
```

This produces output like so:

```
stderr: 219 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 208 chars
stderr: 11 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 218 chars
stderr: 1 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 219 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 219 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 219 chars
Process exited with code 0
stderr: 218 chars
stderr: 1 chars
Process exited with code 0
```

As you can see, sometimes it invokes the callback two times, sometimes one, I had times where it was invoked 3 or 4 times with small reads. Is there a way to ensure all available data is read and not just some of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should listen for the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) event.
The `data` event may be called multiple times - it's called for each received chunk. All chunks should be collected together, for example in an array. The `end` event signals that there is no more data to consume in that readable stream (`child.stderr`).

See below a slightly changed version of your code (with setTimeout and ping instead) using the `end` event:

```
const ChildProcess = require('child_process');

const args = [
                'google.com'
            ];

function runChildProcess() {
    var stdoutChunks = [], stderrChunks = [];
    const child = ChildProcess.spawn('ping', args);

    child.on('exit', (code) =>
        console.log('Process exited with code', code)
    );

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        stdoutChunks = stdoutChunks.concat(data);
    });
    child.stdout.on('end', () => {
        var stdoutContent = Buffer.concat(stdoutChunks).toString();
        console.log('stdout chars:', stdoutContent.length);
        console.log(stdoutContent);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        stderrChunks = stderrChunks.concat(data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('end', () => {
        var stderrContent = Buffer.concat(stderrChunks).toString();
        console.log('stderr chars:', stderrContent.length);
        console.log(stderrContent);
    });

}

setTimeout(runChildProcess, 0);
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you for this! I've overlooked the 'end' event by simply overlooking the fact that `stdout` and `stderr` are streams... :)

Comment: If you just need to print errors to screen... `child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)` will do